# Summability of Fourier series from Banach space point of view

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I am under the impression the following is true (any pointer to a reference would be appreciated ):

**Theorem** (Katznelson?) For any $f \in C[0,1]$ with Fourier coefficients $\{ \hat{f}(n)\}$, there exists $g \in L^2[0,1]$ such that $g \neq 0$ and $|\hat{g}(n)| \leq | \hat{f}(n)|$ for all $n$.

This seems to say that trying to recover $f$ by "thresholding", or shrinking in some fashion, the Fourier coefficients $\{\hat{f}(n)\}$ is a doomed proposition.

On the other hand, standard Fourier series summability methods like Cesaro and Abel just exactly just that---they shrink the Fourier coefficients in some specific way.

*Questions*:

- How do these two facts jive with each other?
- What enables summability methods to bypass Katznelson's counter-example?
- The functions $\{e^{2 \pi i x}\}$ is not even a Schauder basis for $C[0,1]$ yet their linear span is dense in $C[0,1]$, in kind of a particular way. Do Banach space theorists have a name for this kind of "basis"?

Comment: You might want to add something to the theorem to rule out the trivial result $g=0$.

Comment: Why do you believe that the functions $\{e^{2πix}\}$ do not form a Schauder basis?

Comment: And since $C[0,1]\subset L^2[0,1]$, the cited theorem makes no sense. Just take always $g=f$.

Comment: Ok, apparently my belief is incorrect. Could you point to a reference on $C[0,1]$ having $\{e^{2 \pi i n x}\}$ as an unconditional basis? Do you know a theorem whose statement resembles what's stated here, perhaps with $g \notin C[0,1]$?